# How to load website upon selecting MKAnnotation (MapKit, WebKit)

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, mapkit

I'm trying to load the website for a tapped annotation that's been returned from a search - for example if I search for "Starbucks", I want to be able to tap on one of the returned pins' callouts and have the website be loaded. This works fine for my default annotations however when I try it with a search-returned annotation (the "default" condition in my switch statement - `site` is nil, and web view just loads a blank white screen.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let selectedLoc = view.annotation
    if let placeName = selectedLoc?.title! {

        print("Annotation '\(selectedLoc?.title!)' has been selected")

        let selectedPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: (selectedLoc?.coordinate)!, addressDictionary: nil)
        let selectedMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPlacemark)


        switch placeName {
        case "George's":
            if let georgesUrl = URL(string: "http://www.georges-ny.com") {
                self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: georgesUrl))
            }
        case "TGI Friday's":
            if let fridaysUrl = URL(string: "https://www.tgifridays.com") {
                self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: fridaysUrl))
            }
        case "Reserve Cut":
            if let rcUrl = URL(string: "http://reservecut.com") {
                self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: rcUrl))
            }
        case "Bill's Bar & Burger":
            if let billsUrl = URL(string: "http://www.billsbarandburger.com") {
                self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: billsUrl))
            }
        case "O'Hara's":
            if let oharasUrl = URL(string: "http://www.oharaspubnyc.com") {
                self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: oharasUrl))
            }
        default:
            if let site = selectedMapItem.url {
                self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: site))
                print("Website for selected location is: \(site)")
            }
        }
    }


    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    self.view = webView


    // WebView nav bar
    viewWillDisappear(true)

    var backButton = UIImage(named: "back")
    backButton = backButton?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backButton, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleReturn))
    navigationItem.title = "Restaurant Webpage"

}
```

How can I have the site of the selected annotation load correctly when I tap on the callout? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the implementation for `Restaurants`

Comment: @DanielLegler sure, but I actually just edited my question/function so that it doesn't use `Restaurants` at all - now I don't get a crash, but when I tap on the callout for a user-search-returned place, I just get a blank white screen. I changed the build settings to allow arbitrary load so its not the fact that it's http

Comment: When you say `let site = selectedMapItem.url`, do you get a valid URL / the one you expect?

Comment: Sorry I just ninja-edited once more - when I print("site is \(selectedMapItem.url)") in the "default" condition, I see that site is indeed nil - not sure why

Comment: All the results have websites though, I print them out in my search function (which I can post if it'll help!)

Comment: `site` shouldn't be nil if you just initialized it with `if let` though, that's strange. Maybe it is becoming nil when you try to cast a URL as a string with `"\()"` notation?

Comment: It actually doesn't even drop into my if let unwrapping - print statements in there don't print when I select the callout

Comment: I put a print statement to check selectedItem.url outside of that, but inside "default" and it came up nil is what I meant

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17411581/MapViewTTT%202.zip That's the project if you were curious to take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136907/discussion-between-daniel-legler-and-kingtim).